# How PowerShell handles hashtable property values of complex types such as SPListItem that have their own properties?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, hashtable

Consider the following code, where `$p` is a hashtable (`@{}`). Why do `$p.Item.ID` and `$p["Item"].ID` equal `$null`, while `($p.Item | select ID).ID` does not?

```
[DBG]: PS C:\Users\a> $p = @{}; $p.Item = $splist.GetItemById(308);
[DBG]: PS C:\Users\a> $p.Item

...
ID                                 : 308
...

[DBG]: PS C:\Users\a> $p.Item.ID -eq $null
True

[DBG]: PS C:\Users\a> ($p.Item|select ID).ID -eq $null
False
[DBG]: PS C:\Users\a> ($p.Item|select ID).ID
308
```

**Update.** `$p.Item` is a SharePoint List Item. This issue doesn't occur in the case of other simpler(?) types such as `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup`, where `$p.ADGroup.Name` works as expected.

Comment: How are you initialising `$p`? Does `$($p.Item).ID` work? Basically the answer is that you're not accessing the property properly...

Comment: Yes, it works. I'd like to get a more elaborate explanation to accept as answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What I don't understand is how PowerShell handles SPListItems *in hashtable properties* specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Good Powershell le the item as a list normally. You can access all items in a list such as below:

```
Add-PSsnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$SPAssignment = Start-SPAssignment

#Read List
$webS = Get-SPWeb "http://intranet.domain.com.br"
$listS = $webS.Lists["List"]

foreach($item in $listS.Items | Where { $_["ID"] -le 10})
{
    $item["Title"] = "Le id 10"
    $item.Update()

    $id = $item["ID"]
}
Stop-SPAssignment $SPAssignment
```

In my code I'm changing the title to "Le id 10" and getting the Id of the item. Remember that you can do with any column.

Also remember that the values of the object returned by Sharepoint comes with the names of the default SharePoint, eg:

If you have a column named "Dad Mom", the object or the value of the item returns "Dad_x0200_Mom". ($ item ['Dad_x0200_Mom "])

The advantage of Powershell is that returns the states of workflows on the list. But he returns in number. For this there is a table of the workflow states as below:

http://blog.metrostarsystems.com/2011/05/03/sharepoint-2007-workflow-status-codes/

Comment: This may be interesting for someone, but no news for me and doesn't help with the initial question, sorry. And **the advantage** of PowerShell is that it returns **objects** rather than strings and supports pipeline, etc.

Comment: By the way, you're following a **bad practice** by enumerating and filtering `$list.Items` with `Where-Object` rather than using an `SPQuery` to pre-filter the returned items at the database level.

Comment: I remember that I do not use on my desktop. I made just to show you an example. I am certified in Sharepoint, Powershell, Office 365 by Microsoft (MCSD and others). After his assertions refuse to help you and wish you good luck.

Comment: Thanks for trying, I didn't want to be rude, but what you replied with doesn't answer my question, anyway, and please demonstrate good practices, not bad ones however good your intentions, especially if you're certified - don't taint your own reputation. Or, if time presses hard, warn about shortcuts you have to make that the recipient should avoid.

Comment: By the way, you demonstrated one good practice, to be fair - the `*-SPAssignment` - that I acknowledge and thank you for